# Accessing java web service from browser

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, axis

I'm new to java web services. I created a web service which will take 2 numbers as parameters and add. This is the wsdl URL of the web service `http://localhost/TomcatWebService/services/AddService?wsdl`

How can I give the parameters in the URL? In eclipse in web service explorer can give the values. But I want to know the direct URL of this service so I can call from others servers to access it. `AddService` is the class name and it has a method called `add` which has `int x, int y` as parameters.

Comment: Hi Roy, I am suffering from same issue, if you have got solution please refer me too...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'd just name the parameters on the request

AddService?num1=12312&num2=123123

Comment: No it's not working. It says no service available for this URL too /AddService/add?x=1&y=2. Im using Axis (not Axis2)

Comment: It's because you need to pass in the variables as parameters ... so /AddService?params not /add

Comment: it says "Hi there, this is an AXIS service!" But it doesn't show the answer. So without specifying the method name how will it work? what if there are more than one method?

Comment: The method will match the name of the method in the code.  So you would just create multiple methods

Comment: AddService is the class name not the method name. add is the method inside that class. That is why I used /AddService/add?x=1&y=2 this URL. Still it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply call it from the browser by entering a URL. A web service requires the client to send a [SOAP](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) request. Try using a tool like [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org).

Comment: Oki. So from the wsdl url how can I send request from another server? As in how can I pass the parameters and all??

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a SOAP service? SOAP services don't work that way, in your particular case is more suitable a Rest service or just a plain servlet

Comment: I don't have knowledge in REST or plain servlet. Im new to java web service. Do you have any tutorial reference?

Comment: Look this links [Servlets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/servlet-142430.html)  [sample sevlet](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/servlet-3-0-overview.html)